# Printing size of ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm currently trying to detect and print out the size of an ArrayList in Java for a university assignment. This is what I have so far:

**The method for the ArrayList**

```
    public Dog[] obtainAllDogs() {
    Dog[] result = new Dog[dogs.size()];
    result = dogs.toArray(result);
    return result;
}
```

**And the method to set the kennel capacity (ran from the console)**

```
    private void setKennelCapacity() {

     Dog[] currentKennelCapacity = kennel.obtainAllDogs();
     for (Dog d: currentKennelCapacity){
    }
    System.out.println("The current kennel holds " + currentKennelCapacity + ", if you wish to increase it please enter a number below.");
    System.out.print("Enter max number of dogs: ");
    int max = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
    kennel.setCapacity(max);
}
```

It's a little clunky but it does the job at the moment, the interesting part is that it prints out this when ran through the console:

```
The current kennel holds [LDog;@55f96302, if you wish to increase it please enter a number below.
```

It's picking up *something* but not exactly what I want. Currently the kennel size is set to 20, so it should, obviously, print out 20 rather than [LDog;@55f96302.

Can anybody explain this error to me?

If I replace currentKennelCapacity with "d" (from the for each loop), it prints out all of the data from the kennel rather than just the integer 20.

**Here's the current kennel info, if useful:**

```
DogsRUs
20
1
Dinky
1
James Bond
007007
false
1
Gold fingers
```

I'd prefer something to help me understand rather than just a straight solution if possible, helps me to learn :)

Thanks!

Comment: What do you think `"The current kennel holds " + currentKennelCapacity` does? What's the type of `currentKennelCapacity` and which method is invoked when you try to concatenate it to the String?

Comment: I don't see an `ArrayList` anywhere. In any case, you're seeing the default `toString` of an array.

Comment: @DaveNewton He is referring to the array. Silly mistake on his part but thats okay.  You need to do .length to the array to see the size

Comment: @DaveNewton I guess `dogs` is the ArrayList.

Comment: Also is there any reason that `obtainAllDogs` returns an array and not the list itself (or a copy)?

Comment: Huh. Well then he's already *getting* the size of the `ArrayList` via, unoriginally, `size()`.

Comment: An array is not an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`currentKennelCapacity` is an array. If you want to print how many elements it can hold you should use `currentKennelCapacity.length`:

```
System.out.println("The current kennel holds " + currentKennelCapacity.length + ", if you wish to increase it please enter a number below.");
```

Note this is not a good name for a variable that is supposed to reference an array, since it looks like it should be a number.

Answer (score 2):

What you have done is print the array itself, not the size of the array.  And in Java, arrays are objects too, but they don't override [`Object`'s `toString` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--), which is responsible for the `[LDog;@55f96302` output.

> [T]his method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

All arrays have a `length` attribute you can use.

```
System.out.println("The current kennel holds " + currentKennelCapacity.length
    + ", if you wish to increase it please enter a number below.");
```

What was confusing was your choice of variable name, `currentKennelCapacity`, such that the name describes something else other than what it really is.  I would have named it something more accurate, such as `currentKennel`.  This may have contributed to confusing yourself about what would be printed when the variable was printed.

As an aside, you can use [`Arrays.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-java.lang.Object:A-) if you want to print the contents of the array.

```
System.our.println(Arrays.toString(currentKennel));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [].length

```
System.out.println("The current kennel holds " + currentKennelCapacity + ", if you wish to increase it please enter a number below.");
```

To

```
System.out.println("The current kennel holds " + currentKennelCapacity.length + ", if you wish to increase it please enter a number below.");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to print out the Dog array, which cannot be converted into a String, that's why you're seeing those numbers. It's the array's hash code.

You can find the size of an array through its length property like this:

```
System.out.println("The current kennel holds " +
    currentKennelCapacity.length
    + ", if you wish to increase it please enter a number below.");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your print statement is outside of your for each loop.
Secondly, you could try and research about overloading `toString()` method. That will help you understand why you cannot print the array, the way you want. Lastly, as others already mentioned, you need to use `array.length` to get a size of array.